# How to avoid conflict collection model in query builder union in laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, union, query-builder

I have 2 models Test and Exam; table related to these model have the same columns: id, name, point;
i want to retrieve the 2 data by using union:

```
$test = Test::where('point', '>', 10);
$exam = Exam::where('point', '>', 10);

$result = $test->union($exam)->get();
```

i got all list of test and exam fusioned; but when checking the collection, it said that the model used is always Test even if the row is Exam; and vice versa if i use `$exam->union($test)` all the collection is Exam;

Is there a way to do union and get the exact model collection?

Comment: Why are you unioning two different model types? If you want them treated independently, just add them to the collection.

Comment: cause i want the two model in my data returned as if the Exam is considered as Test but the two have different treatment after i got the unioned data, example i have to function treatTest and treatExam, so on my data, if the item is test it pass to treatTest and if exam it pass to treatExam but the result returned is unioned in the same data